# The Ising Model and Computational Complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hard, physics

I've been told recently that one can use the Ising model can find solutions to certain NP-hard problems, such as Clique, although it doesn't do so in polynomial time.

Googling gets a few Arxiv results but where might I find an introduction to this interesting relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the minimal energy configuration in the Ising model is NP-hard, and many problems can be directly reduced to it. For a list, including Karp's original 21 NP-hard problem see e.g. [Ising formulations of many NP problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5843.pdf). The Ising model is also equivalent to [unconstrained quadratic binary optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_unconstrained_binary_optimization) which also can be used to model a large number of other NP-complete problems, see e.g. [A unified modeling and solution framework for combinatorial optimization problems](http://leeds-faculty.colorado.edu/glover/fred%20pubs/363%20-%20xQx%20-%20%20Unified%20Framework%20Tutorial.pdf).